# Cannot read property 'innerHTML' of undefined

Tags: javascript, salesforce, innerhtml

I'm trying to test an app in salesforce lightning component, but when I load the app (I try [this](https://gist.github.com/jeffdonthemic/39791ab40112a81f0168) app) I got the error

> Cannot read property 'innerHTML' of undefined

The associated code is here :

```
 !(function(t, e) {
     var r = function(e) {
             (t.execScript || function(e) {
                 t["eval"].call(t, e)
             })(e)
         },
         i = function(t, e) {
             return t instanceof(e || Array)
         },
         s = document,
         n = "getElementsByTagName",
         a = "length",
         c = "readyState",
         l = "onreadystatechange",
         u = s[n]("script"),
         o = u[u[a] - 1],
         f = o.innerHTML.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g, "");
     if (!t.ljs) {
         var h = o.src.match(/checkLoaded/) ? 1 : 0,
             d = s[n]("head")[0] || s.documentElement,
             p = function(t) {
                 var e = {};
                 e.u = t.replace(/#(=)?([^#]*)?/g, function(t, r, i) {
                     e[r ? "f" : "i"] = i;
                     return ""
                 });
                 return e
             },
             v = function(t, e, r) {
                 var i = s.createElement(t),
                     n;
                 if (r) {
                     if (i[c]) {
                         i[l] = function() {
                             if (i[c] === "loaded" || i[c] === "complete") {
                                 i[l] = null;
                                 r()
                             }
                         }
                     } else {
                         i.onload = r
                     }
                 }
                 for (n in e) {
                     e[n] && (i[n] = e[n])
                 }
                 d.appendChild(i)
             },
             m = function(t, e) {
                 if (this.aliases && this.aliases[t]) {
                     var r = this.aliases[t].slice(0);
                     i(r) || (r = [r]);
                     e && r.push(e);
                     return this.load.apply(this, r)
                 }
                 if (i(t)) {
                     for (var s = t[a]; s--;) {
                         this.load(t[s])
                     }
                     e && t.push(e);
                     return this.load.apply(this, t)
                 }
                 if (t.match(/\.js\b/) || t.match(/\.sfjs\b/)) {
                     t = t.replace(".sfjs", "");
                     return this.loadjs(t, e)
                 } else if (t.match(/\.css\b/) || t.match(/\.sfcss\b/)) {
                     t = t.replace(".sfcss", "");
                     return this.loadcss(t, e)
                 } else {
                     return this.loadjs(t, e)
                 }
             },
             y = {},
             g = {
                 aliases: {},
                 loadjs: function(t, r) {
                     var i = p(t);
                     t = i.u;
                     if (y[t] === true) {
                         r && r();
                         return this
                     } else if (y[t] !== e) {
                         if (r) {
                             y[t] = function(t, e) {
                                 return function() {
                                     t && t();
                                     e && e()
                                 }
                             }(y[t], r)
                         }
                         return this
                     }
                     y[t] = function(e) {
                         return function() {
                             y[t] = true;
                             e && e()
                         }
                     }(r);
                     r = function() {
                         y[t]()
                     };
                     v("script", {
                         type: "text/javascript",
                         src: t,
                         id: i.i,
                         onerror: function(t) {
                             if (i.f) {
                                 var e = t.currentTarget;
                                 e.parentNode.removeChild(e);
                                 v("script", {
                                     type: "text/javascript",
                                     src: i.f,
                                     id: i.i
                                 }, r)
                             }
                         }
                     }, r);
                     return this
                 },
                 loadcss: function(t, e) {
                     var r = p(t);
                     t = r.u;
                     y[t] || v("link", {
                         type: "text/css",
                         rel: "stylesheet",
                         href: t,
                         id: r.i
                     });
                     y[t] = true;
                     e && e();
                     return this
                 },
                 load: function() {
                     var t = arguments,
                         r = t[a];
                     if (r === 1 && i(t[0], Function)) {
                         t[0]();
                         return this
                     }
                     m.call(this, t[0], r <= 1 ? e : function() {
                         g.load.apply(g, [].slice.call(t, 1))
                     });
                     return this
                 },
                 addAliases: function(t) {
                     for (var e in t) {
                         this.aliases[e] = i(t[e]) ? t[e].slice(0) : t[e]
                     }
                     return this
                 }
             };
         if (h) {
             var j, b, x, A;
             for (j = 0, b = u[a]; j < b; j++) {
                 (A = u[j].getAttribute("src")) && (y[A.replace(/#.*$/, "")] = true)
             }
             x = s[n]("link");
             for (j = 0, b = x[a]; j < b; j++) {
                 (x[j].rel === "stylesheet" || x[j].type === "text/css") && (y[x[j].getAttribute("href").replace(/#.*$/, "")] = true)
             }
         }
         t.ljs = g
     }
     f && r(f)
 })(window);
```

But I'm a novice with javascript and I don't know how to fix it (i'd like to test this app)

Thanks !

Comment: Please, please format your code properly. This is almost impossible to read.

Comment: Please do not post minified code! It's impossible to read. http://unminify.com/ can help with this :)

Comment: Oh yes sorry I've fixed that I think...

Answer (score 1):

That just means that the element that you are looking for does not exist:

```js
var elementNotFound = document.getElementById("noSuchId"); // Does not exist
console.log("The element:", elementNotFound);
console.log(elementNotFound.innerHTML);
```

As you have posted the mimified JavaScript and no HTML, I don't know how to help further then saying: Make use the ID you are using to find the element is correct and has no spelling mistakes, and that the element is actually in the HTML.

Hope this helps.

Comment: So, it would mean that the element "script" does not exist ? But it seems that this element exist, as we can see it in the code I post...

Comment: Not quite. I mean that the JavaScript is trying to find an element in the HTML. One way you can do this is how I did in the code above: `getElementById` that means that `<div id="noSuchId"></div>` would be returned by `document.getElementById("noSuchId");` and `innerHTML` is a function of what is returned. You are getting an error because the HTML element that you are looking for with JavaSript does not exist.