# Google Maps google.maps.places.PlacesService typeerror undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

Following the code nearly exactly from: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/places#TextSearchRequests

When

```
service = new google.maps.places.PlacesService(map);
```

is called, the console gives me an undefined type error:

```
util.js:22 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'innerHTML' of undefined
```

My code is below. Anyone know what is happening?

HTML

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyDo5LxyVUv5EwGQBwaveIF4d0MaIVD_Dd8&libraries=places"></script>
```

JS

```
function initMap(userLocation) {
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
        center: userLocation,
        zoom: radius
    });

    infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
}

function textSearch(query) {
    var service;

    var request = {
        location: userLocation,
        query: query
    };

    service = new google.maps.places.PlacesService(map);
    service.textSearch(request, cb);
}

function cb(results, status) {
    if (status == google.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus.OK) {
        for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
            var place = results[i];
            // createMarker(results[i]);
            console.log(place);
        }
    }
}

initMap(userLocation); // userLocation is a latLong obj, set elsewhere in the code.
textSearch('movies');
```

Comment: util.js:22. How does line 22 in util.js look like?

Comment: It's just a bunch of minified code. Util.js is something included in the browser, and the error is caused somewhere else in the code. This question gives some info on that, but the answer to that question doesn't apply to my situation: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20997672/google-maps-places-is-undefined](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20997672/google-maps-places-is-undefined)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38785861/cannot-read-property-innerhtml-of-undefined

Comment: Try to load the API asynchronously and use the callback as described in the documentation. Just to be sure that all classes are loaded correctly. https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/get-api-key#specify-a-key-when-loading-the-api